# SQL Server - Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
sts_id int 
, [status1] int
, [status2] int
, [status3] int
, [status4] int
)
INSERT INTO test values
('1','999','0','0','0'),
('1','100','0','0','0'),
('2','200','999','0','0'),
('3','500','600','999','0'),
('4','200','700','900','998'),
('4','300','400','800','999')
```

In SQL Server (2016), I have a query for the above table to get the highest value <= 900 (if possible)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   sts_id
 , CASE
       WHEN status1 > 0 AND status2 = 0 THEN status1
       WHEN status2 > 900 AND status3 = 0 THEN status1
       WHEN status2 BETWEEN 1 AND 900 AND status3 = 0 THEN status2
       WHEN status3 > 900 AND status4 = 0 THEN status2
       WHEN status3 BETWEEN 1 AND 900 AND status4 = 0 THEN status3
       WHEN status4 > 900 THEN status3 WHEN status4 BETWEEN 1 AND 900 THEN status4
       ELSE status1
   END AS 'status'
FROM test
```

Giving me this:

```
| sts_ID | status |
|--------|--------|
|  1     |  100   |
|  1     |  999   |
|  2     |  200   |
|  3     |  600   |
|  4     |  800   |
|  4     |  900   |
```

I then join this onto another table on the sts_id, and get the max(status) value.

However, I am not concerned with statuses above 900, and sts_id 1 for example is going to give me 999, even though I would prefer it to give me 100.

Is there any way I can incorporate some kind of CASE to get the next value if there is one available for a single ID? Would dense_rank() possibly help?

Comment: So are you trying to get the MAX(status) for each sts_id, while ignoring cases where status > 900?

Comment: Your posted query doesn't do what you say it does, making this whole question very unclear to me.   What if the second row of your table had a `status4` value of 200...would you still want to return 100 for `ID 1`?

Comment: The biggest issue I see is the table design. You have repeating groups here which violates 1NF making it challenging to query.

Comment: Your request make no sense! What do you mean by "`next value`". Your table has no ordered data and SQL Server does not guarantee that the rows will be returned in specific order, unless you use `ORDER BY`. How can we know that 999 is before 100 or after?!? If you want to get the min then you can use min but there is no "next" if there is no order :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this would be easier if you unpivot your table into a single `status` column.  Here is a method with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT sts_id, MAX(status) MaxStatus
FROM TEST
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (status1), 
                    (status2), 
                    (status3), 
                    (status4)
            ) A (status)
WHERE STATUS <= 900
GROUP BY sts_id
```

Result:

```
STS_ID  MaxStatus
1       100
2       200
3       600
4       900
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `apply` and `max()`, but like this:

```
SELECT sts_id, v.MaxStatus
FROM TEST CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(status) as MaxStatus
      FROM (VALUES (status1), 
                   (status2), 
                   (status3), 
                   (status4)
           ) v(status)
      WHERE STATUS <= 900
     ) v;
```

This may look essentially the same as Aaron's answer.  However, there is a fundamental difference.  The aggregation is happening within a row, with at most 4 values.  This should be very fast. Putting the aggregation outside the `apply` means that the entire data needs to be aggregated -- and is a bit more cumbersome as you want to add columns.

In addition, this will return all rows, even when no statuses meet those conditions.  If you want a row to be filtered in this case, then add `where maxstatus is not null` to the outer query.

Comment: @AaronDietz . . . The point is t hat no aggregation is needed in the outer query to aggregate the values *within* a row.  But I see the sample data  has duplicate `sts_id`.  With the reasonable (but I don't see explicit) assumption that the OP wants one row per `sts_id`, you're answer is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gordon.  I deleted my comment since half of it was commenting on a typo, but for future viewers I asked if it would still be better if an outer `MAX()... GROUP BY` was needed to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe? (Referencing your final table output as `inline_view`):

```
        SELECT sts_id, MAX(status)
        FROM
        (
        SELECT sts_id, status, CASE WHEN status > 900 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS status_above_900
        FROM inline_view
        ) a1
        WHERE status_above_900 = 1
        GROUP BY sts_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement gives you the highest status form `status4` to `status1`, that is equal to or below to `900`.

```
SELECT sts_id,
       CASE
         WHEN status4 > 0
              AND status4 <= 900 THEN
           status4
         WHEN status3 > 0
              AND status3 <= 900 THEN
           status3
         WHEN status2 > 0
              AND status2 <= 900 THEN
           status2
         WHEN status1 > 0
              AND status1 <= 900 THEN
           status1
       END status
       FROM test;
```

Result:

```
sts_id | status
-----: | -----:
     1 |
     1 |    100
     2 |    200
     3 |    600
     4 |    900
     4 |    800
```

For one of the `sts_id = 1` there is no such status, so `NULL` is returned for that.

But you say, you want `100` for `sts_id = 1`. So, I'm not sure if you rather want an aggregation and only one row per `sts_id`.

If you do, one possible way was to first get all the status per `sts_id` with a `UNION` (it's fine to eliminate duplicates here as we do that with the `GROUP BY` later anyway), filtered for values less than or equal to `900` and then `GROUP BY sts_id` and get the maximum value per `sts_id`.

```
SELECT sts_id,
       max(status) status
       FROM (SELECT sts_id,
                    status1 status
                    FROM test
                    WHERE status1 <= 900
             UNION
             SELECT sts_id,
                    status2 status
                    FROM test
                    WHERE status2 <= 900
             UNION
             SELECT sts_id,
                    status3 status
                    FROM test
                    WHERE status3 <= 900
             UNION
             SELECT sts_id,
                    status4 status
                    FROM test
                    WHERE status4 <= 900) x
       GROUP BY sts_id;
```

Result:

```
sts_id | status
-----: | -----:
     1 |    100
     2 |    200
     3 |    600
     4 |    900
```